# How to import a module from outside the directory?

Tags: python, import, module, path

How do I access the module that is outside the directory? for example, I want to access a function from `xyz.py` inside `abc.py` which is inside folder `X`:

```
- Project/
   -> X -|
         |-> abc.py
         |-> lmn.py

   -> xyz.py
```

Just writing `from xyz import func` or `from Project.xyz import func` inside `abc.py` doesn't work.
I have also referred to few other solutions and tried to set the path using system, but even that doesn't work:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'path/to/Project')
from xyz import func
```

Comment: then your folders path is wrong

Comment: all the options you provided above are working

Comment: Somehow it says, module xyz not found in all the cases

Comment: the path you provided in this question is the path you used in your project?

Comment: No, that is not the path I used in my project. It should have worked in the 1st case atleast ``` from xyz import func``` but even that is not working

Comment: then show me the real path of your project, maybe you miss spelled something and thats why it doesnt found'

Comment: its /home/Project

Comment: i meant all the inside components, the real tree of project.

Comment: /home/Project contains xyz.py and folder x, this folder x, further contains abc.py and lmn.py. So I want to use function func from xyz.py inside abc.py.

Answer (score 0):

What version of python are you using?

If you're using an older version you may need to add a `__init__.py` file at the Project/ level like so

```
- Project/
   -> __init__.py 
   -> X -|
         |-> abc.py
         |-> lmn.py

   -> xyz.py
```

Python 3.3+ should have [implicit namespace packages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/), but before that you'll need to add the init file to import it and treat it like a module.

Comment: I am using python 3.8

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
from ..xyz import func
```