# relative python imports. What is the difference between single dot and no dot

Tags: python

Thats quite basic but still I am a bit puzzled. I have this toy example where I try to import a function from `my_module.py` which looks like:

```
## my_module.py

def say_hi():
    print('Hi!')
```

See attached pic for my project tree
[image]

The import statement `from .my_module import say_hi` gives the `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`. However it works fine as `from my_module import say_hi`.

I thought these statements were equivalent, especially given the presence of `__init__.py`. PyCharm too seems to be happy in both cases, ie a mouse-hover and ctrl key combination over the word my_module, highlights the word.

Comment: Because you are running `main.py` as a top level script, it must use absolute imports to find something in the same directory. Generally, your top level script (the one running as `__main__` should be outside of the package. 
  All imports within the package should be relative, and then scripts outside of the package use an absolute import to pull in the entire package.  That's probably not the best explanation, but that's basically the issue.

Comment: See also: [This similar recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77016132/import-from-another-file-inside-the-same-module-and-running-from-a-main-py-outsi/77016341#77016341), as well as [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3) and what I consider to be [the definitive explanation of relative imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time/14132912#14132912)

Comment: Hi again....since I did find both of your comments really helpful, If you want just make them as an answer and I will be happy to accept it so you can get some credit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relative imports are not PATH relative, they are PACKAGE relative.  They only work within a module that is part of a package when imported by a script outside of the package.

A module is considered to be in a package if it's `__name__` at the time of execution contains a `.` (example: `import my_package.utilities`).  The value of `__name__` is set to the filename preceded by any packages and subpackage directory names.

So, as an example, if a script outside of your `my_proj` directory included
`import my_proj`, then the two .py files inside would have `__name__` set to `'my_proj.main'` and `'my_proj.my_module'` respectively when they are imported as members of the package.

When you execute any script as the top-level script, for example via `python script.py`, it's `__name__` value is set to `'__main__'`, meaning it is not considered to be part of a package by the import system, even if its in a directory with the file you're trying to import from.  Therefore, the top-level script MUST use absolute imports only.

If you need `main.py` in your given structure to function both as a top-level script and also if its imported as part of the package and executed as a module, then you can use try/except to attempt a relative import first, then fall back to an absolute import.

```py
# main.py
try:
    from .my_module import say_hi
except ImportError:
    from my_module import say_hi

if __name__ == '__main__':
    say_hi()
```

I consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132912/17030540) to be the definitive explanation of relative imports in Python on Stack Overflow, and it's where I learned most of this (and cross-referenced while writing this answer)

See also this similar post I answered a few days before this one: [Import from another file inside the same module and running from a main.py outside the module throws an import error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77016132/import-from-another-file-inside-the-same-module-and-running-from-a-main-py-outsi?noredirect=1&lq=1)