# Python sibling relative import error: 'no known parent package'

Tags: python, python-import, relative-import

I want to import a module from a subpackage so I went here [Relative importing modules from parent folder subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057464/relative-importing-modules-from-parent-folder-subfolder) and since it was not working I read all the literature here on stack and found a smaller problem that I can reproduce but cannot solve.

I want to use relative imports because I don't wanna deal with sys.path etc and I don't wanna install every module of my project to be imported everywhere. I wanna make it work with relative imports.

My project structure:

```
project/
    __init__.py
    bar.py
    foo.py
    main.py
```

bar.py:

```
from .foo import Foo

class Bar():

    @staticmethod
    def get_foo():
        return Foo()
```

foo.py:

```
class Foo():
    pass
```

main.py:

```
from bar import Bar

def main():
    f = Bar.get_foo()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am running the project code from terminal with `python main.py` and I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "**omitted** project/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bar import Bar
  File "**omitted** project/bar.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .foo import Foo
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Why am I getting this error? It seems that bar doesn't recognize project as the parent package but:

- `__init__.py` is in place
- `bar.py` is being run as a module not a script since it is called from main and not from the command line (so `__package__` and `__name__` should be in place to help solve the relative import [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time))

Why am I getting this error? What am I getting wrong? I have worked for a while just adding the parent of cwd to the PYTHONPATH but I wanna fix this once and for all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be running your project from the *parent* of project dir as:

```
$ python -m project.main # note no .py
```

This tells python that there is a *package* named `project` and inside it a *module* named `main` - then relative and absolute imports work correctly - once you change the import in main in either of

```
from .bar import Bar # relative
from project.bar import Bar # absolute
```

Comment: Let me think about it but I think this might be the best solutions since it keeps the project structure intact and doesn't use sys.path

Comment: This is the actual pattern for running a python script from inside a package @UmbertoFontanazza

Answer (score 1):

I recommend looking at this thread on [relative imports in python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3). I was able to get your import working 2 different ways:

1. Moving main.py to the parent directory and adjusting your import. In this case the structure is updated to a more traditional style where the package scripts are in their own directory.

Updated Structure:

```
main.py
project/
    __init__.py
    bar.py
    foo.py
```

main.py:

```
from project.bar import Bar

def main():
    f = Bar.get_foo()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

2. If you want to keep your current structure instead of having the package scripts in their own directory then try adding the parent directory of your package to `PYTHONPATH`

main.py:

```
import sys
import os
SCRIPT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(SCRIPT_DIR))
from project.bar import Bar

def main():
    f = Bar.get_foo()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Instead of editing sys.path, it would be better to set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable before running the script.  If you still want to edit `sys.path`, then instead of appending to the end, it would be better to use `sys.path.insert(1, os.path.dirname(SCRIPT_DIR))` so that the local directory is early in the search path, instead of last, where another installed package of the same name might be imported instead of the local file.

Comment: What is generating the error in my example though?

Comment: @UmbertoFontanazza  `main.py` is not importing `bar` as part of a package because the import statement doesn't include a `.` As a result `bar` cannot import `foo` using a relative import, as relative imports are only valid within a package.

Comment: @UmbertoFontanazza read through the "Accessing a module NOT through its containing package" section in the top-voted answer to the question you linked. That covers exactly this problem.

Comment: Editing `sys.path` can lead to subtle bugs and is only useful in very special cases (when you have no control on a library's position in the file system). Moving the main out of the package breaks encapsulation. The correct solution is simply using the `-m` switch when running a script inside a package (running from the package parent dir)

Answer (score 1):

@kevin41's answer is solid.  I wanted to add some additional info that seemed a bit much for comments.

As a general rule, your top level script, the one being run by Python and which has `__name__=="__main__"`, should NOT be inside any package.

By running main.py inside of package, the package itself is never imported.
Relative imports are **package relative, not path relative**.  Python knows it is working with a package import and should use relative imports based on the `__package__` special variable being set, and `__package__` gets set based on using an import with a `.`, such as `import package.bar`, in which case `__package__=="package"`

The `__package__` special variable is never set for the top level script, which is why main.py must use absolute imports.
When main.py imports bar using an absolute import, the value of the `__package__` special variable while bar is being processed is also None, because bar was not imported as part of a package, therefore it can't use relative imports either.

With some small changes we can observe how bar imports foo based on how main is importing bar.

bar.py

```
try:
    from .foo import Foo
    print("Using relative import")
except ImportError:
    from foo import Foo
    print("Using absoloute import")
print(f"{__package__=}  {__name__=}  {__file__=}")

class Bar():

    @staticmethod
    def get_foo():
        return Foo()
```

Output when running main.py as you have it configured:

```
Using absoloute import
__package__=''  __name__='bar'  __file__='c:\\Users\\...\\package\\bar.py'
```

Moving main.py outside of the package directory and changing the import to `from package.bar import Bar`, gives us the output

```
Using relative import
__package__='package'  __name__='package.bar'  __file__='c:\\Users\\...\\package\\bar.py'
```

The correct solution is to move your top level script outside of the package folder.  If your application needs a primary script within the package, then that script should use relative imports and it should be imported by another top-level script outside of the package.

Example structure:

```
project/
    __init__.py
    bar.py
    foo.py
    main.py
app.py
```

main.py first line:

```
from .bar import Bar
```

app.py

```
from package.main import main

main()
```

Additional relevant posts:

- [Import from another file inside the same module and running from a main.py outside the module throws an import error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77016132/import-from-another-file-inside-the-same-module-and-running-from-a-main-py-outsi/77016341#77016341)
- [relative python imports. What is the difference between single dot and no dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77091688/relative-python-imports-what-is-the-difference-between-single-dot-and-no-dot/77120636#77120636)